# Python Bot with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to code a bot on twitter using the tweepy lib but I'm not getting results. I need help for code to reply to tweets that mentioned me.

```
search = '@MoviesRandom'
numberOfTweets = 10
phrase = movies()  # Here im using a function declared by me before. Doesn't having errors here

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberOfTweets):
    try:
        tweetId = tweet.user.idusername
        username = tweet.user.screen_name
        api.update_status("@" + username + " " + phrase, in_reply_to_status_id=tweetId)
        print("Replied with " + phrase)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
```

Comment: sory for the code, im begginer here.

Comment: Is there a typo in your code? the `tweetId` line looks like you've put "username" on the end. What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely caused by this line here

```
tweetId = tweet.user.idusername
```

There is no such object called `idusername` and as @Andy mentioned it, it should just be the `id` object.

```
tweetId = tweet.user.id
```